# updating a form after using upload.php for file upload.

Tags: php, forms, parameters, upload

I have a php page (called add_ship.php) with a form to populate a database, including a file upload. This works via a separate file upload.php (shown below).

What I can't get to work is when a file is uploaded successfully, I've created a link to go back to add_ship.php, with the name of the image as a parameter... how do I get this parameter to fill the correct field in the form, and also, if a user has already entered a few fields, THEN selects upload image, surely all the rest of the data is lost - is there a way to not loose what's been entered (so ideally retuning to add_ship.php and just adding the file name into the correct field?)

Many thanks

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Image succsefuly uploaded. " . "<br>" . "<br>";
    ?>
    <a href="add_ship.php?file_name= <?php echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] ?>">Click Hereto return to Add Ship page</a>
<?php


    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "../images/ships/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct that by navigating to a separate page to perform the file upload, you will lose unsaved form data. There are a number of ways around this:

1) don't use a separate page. Handle the file upload in add_ship.php. Basically you'd just move the code from upload.php into add_ship.php. When the upload is complete, then process the rest of the form data.

2) Put your upload form into a dialog (using jquery .dialog(), for example) and upload the file asynchronously (using jquery .ajax(), for example).

You can come up with ways of tossing the form data back and forth between two separate pages, but they are all rather tedious and prone to error.

Regarding the original question, there are a number of things that could be going wrong. The first that comes to mind is special characters inside the file name.

Comment: thank you Nathan, I think I'll look at those suggestions and see how far I get. Best x